# Why can't I get touch input (Unity with C#) to work?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to finish the Android game I've been working on. I first made to controlling mechanism using mouse, but as it needs to work with multitouch for the shot button and the aiming area, I tried converting the script to touch input according to tutorials but it doesn't seem to register any touch.

Also, I wanted the script to record whether one of the touches, regardless of order, was placed on the area for either shot or aiming control when it begun, and place that in a Vector3 list. When respectable touch is lifted, it resets the value in that list index. Then, for example, the shooting script checks whether one of the list values is within the range of the shooting button radius, so it activates the weapon loading. It keeps telling me this error:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
>   index

```
Here are the class codes for the touch inputs and for the shooting button:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TouchControls : MonoBehaviour

{
    public static bool shotTime = false;
    public static List <Vector3> position = new List<Vector3>(2);
    public static bool moveTime = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        position[0] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        position[1] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount && i < 2; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("Touch");
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);
            Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            pos.z = 0;
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                position[i] = pos;
            }
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                position[i] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        Debug.Log(position[0] + position[1]);
    }
}
```

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShotButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool time = false;
    private Vector3 scale;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        scale = gameObject.transform.localScale;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        {
            if (Vector2.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, TouchControls.position[0]) < scale.x || Vector2.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, TouchControls.position[1]) < scale.x)
            {
                time = true;
                gameObject.transform.localScale = scale * 0.9f;
            }
            else
            {
                time = false;
                gameObject.transform.localScale = scale;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong with the code? How can I fix it?

Comment: You use your List of positions like an array so you can replace List with array. Can you try to change your variable like that : `public static Vector3[] position;` and initialise it in your start method : `position = new Vector3[2]` ?

Comment: @AlexAR That creates an array? Because in the Unity documentation it says Array is only available in JavaScript. And now it says "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance..."

Comment: You can use array as I wrote it in my previous comment, but after reading your code another time, I think that's not the problem :  If's there's no touch, you enter in the `for` loop and try to get touches 1 and 2. You need to ensure you got a touch before enter the loop. You can add `if(!Input.touchCount > 0) return;` before the `for` loop in your update method. And you need to count touches before try to get theirs positions !

Comment: But the Input.touchCount should return 0 when there are no touches, and the rule for the for loop is "as long as less than Input.touchCount", so it should only enter the loop if there is at least one touch.

Comment: Yes but if you have 1 touch, your code does not work.

Comment: How so? And I'm testing this on the computer before there is any touch input. What breaks the code is the ShotButton class. I don't understand how else to call the array from the TouchControls class.

Answer (score 0):

For Lists, this is how an element at a certain index is fetched

```
public T this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        if (index >= this._size)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("...");
        return this._items[index];
    }
    set
    {
        if (index >= this._size)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("...");
        this._items[index] = value;
    }
}
```

So what it does is that it checks `_size` variable instead of capacity, and throws the exception if the index you're requesting is greater than it.

`_size` is initialized to 0 unless you pass a non-empty collection into the constructor, and changes value when you use the `Add`, `RemoveAt`, `Clear`, etc methods.

The `Capacity` of the list represents how much memory the list currently has set aside for the current objects and objects to be added to it. The Count (here `_size`) of the list is how many items have actually been added to the list.

So you need to add elements to the list. I think the first script's `Start()` isn't called (so the size stays 0) probably because the script isn't enabled.

You can make sure `Start()` is called or put the `Start()` logic in `Awake()` as per your needs which is called even if the `Start()` method isn't called. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually changed it to an array as suggested in a comment above, but now I get this error "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance" when trying to reference it in the shot button class. Why?

Comment: Yes, it is static. I'm not not my computer but the update was basically declaring the Vector3 array "public static Vector3[] position;" in the upper end of the class, and then in Start I gave position 2 slots as "position = new Vector3[2]" and I even gave slot [0] and [1] the value "new Vector3[0, 0, 0] even though it's probably not required. I then try to call it from the ShotButton class in the update method with "TouchControls.position[0]" and [1] but that returns the reference error.